# Yoshino Cherry Tree leaves turning brown and drying

Tags: fruit-trees, cherries

i planted a Yoshino cherry tree 4 month ago(end of summer, beginning of fall), tree was growing healthy but suddenly the leaves started turning brown, from the tip to the back, tips of the leave are dry, thanks for the help
[image]

Comment: What part of the world are you in?